# Openfire: Archive Message NULL Participants

Tags: php, mysql, linux, chat, openfire

I have openfire(Version:Openfire 3.9.3) installed in my linux server.It was working fine before 2 days with all functionality .I am concentrating on Archive Message plugin.
What is issue : 
 1. when i start chat with user it shows Message received.
 2. When i click to see participant of that conversation is shows null entry.

I check(repaired,truncate,recreate ) all tables listed below

> - ofConParticipant
> - ofMessageArchive
> - ofConversation

among above.(ofMessageArchive,ofConversation) tables get perfect record entries.
But (ofConParticipant) table did not get any record.
ofConParticipant is refrence table to (ofConversation).

I attached my screenshot whats happening.

[image: What is issue]
This is correct
[image: This is correct]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the MYSql process list . I think your resources are full. I also had a same issue . Might help you.

Comment: you were not actually right ,but partially true...i found the solution

Comment: What's the solution? I have the same issue. It'd be nice that you share your solution.